# Updating existing prices with different VAT. PHP vs Triggers

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a situation where products are exported from the database into a .csv file. But, in database prices are stored as net price and I have to export prices for Austria with 20% VAT and for German export with 19% VAT.

Also in settings for the export, there is an option to set up from which field price to be taken.

So, is a good solution to add two new fields to the database table (priceVAT20 and priceVAT19) and update table with setting up priceVAT20=netPrice * 1.2 and priceVAT19=netPrice * 1.19. 
And after this, to create a trigger that will fill these two new fields
with  priceVAT20=netPrice * 1.2 and priceVAT19=netPrice * 1.19 on inserting new record or updating netPrice.

The module that is exporting products is too much big and exporting to much different types of files with products, orders...So, for that I think that is not good

Comment: In a word:  no .

Comment: Could you please shortly explain your answer?

Comment: Store the vat rates in a separate table, e.g. vat_rates(country_code,rate)

Comment: I have a table for all products. There is field article_price where net price is saved. Why I will need a separate table where prices with 20% and 19% VAT will be stored for each product?

Comment: Also, Vat percent is stored in the different table depending on the country. But I am asking about the prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share with you my solution.
I decided to not use triggers and after two days of debugging, I found the correct function for my exports and there depending on the country, I multiplied the price by 19 or 20%.

Also, I've discussed with few guys and all of them suggested me to not use triggers because if something has to be changed in the future, it's gonna be really hard.

Thanks again for your help.